# update an I'd to previous unique_id record if inserted record value is like previous unique field value

Tags: php, mysql

Hope this  my question get answered!
I have a database that contains record of  musicians : musicfile; artistname; albumcover etc. Each entry is entered throug a form but unlike the musician region and music genre that is using html form select option, the artistname is form text input

Input type="text" name="artistname"

So to get artist id am sending an auto increment  hidden field value for every new insert.

My questrion is this: if auto increment value is generated for every  new entry. With artistname, musicfile etc, how I can make  artist_id which is generated by the hidden auto increment to have the same value if the artistname inserted is like the previous artistname inserted without generate an auto increment again for entry with the same artistname

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 SQL tables. One for the music files and one for the artists. 
Or, in my opinion, you can use artist name as artist_id, if it is unique.

Comment: Thanks@j-hong; if I use a unique key on the artist column that will mean only one music track from that artist will be inserted. So that is why I  choose to assign id for each artist entered. I just want the  id of same artistname. Entered to be equal

Comment: If you want a numeric id, you should make 2 tables.  But I suggest, if you have a problem do more code, just use artist name for getting all songs of him. Don't make unique key.